# Does adding const to local variables affect their scope and compiler optimizations?

Tags: c++, constants, compiler-optimization

Say I have the following code:

```
int foo () {
    int const x = 0;
    return x;
}
```

Is the compiler allowed to move x to the global scope?

What about in the following scenaro? Can `res2` vary depending on opimizations?

```
std::set<int const *> addrs;

int foo () {
    int const x = 0;
    addrs.insert(&x);
    return addrs.size();
}

void bar () {
    int res1 = foo();
    int res2 = foo();
}
```

Comment: I would imagine the compiler would replace the first one with `0` every time it is called.

Comment: No, the compiler cannot move x to the global scope.  But I don't think that's exactly what you mean.

Comment: what is the question concerning the second example?

Comment: A compiler will convert your code into an intermediate, where scope means something different then in the front-end form. The question makes no sense.

Comment: @VladLazarenko not really a dupe. (at least not of that question) Note that there *is* a catch to this question which makes it mildly interesting - the UB in the second part.

Comment: Perhaps you're mixing up scope with storage location.  Sure, the compiler could keep it in static storage (such as `section .rodata` or `.bss` as if it has been `static const int x = 0;`) instead of materializing it on the stack every call.  Of course, you can't depend on this, it's still UB to deref a pointer to an object that's gone out of scope, but yes it might produce different results (symptoms of such a bug) in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the compiler can't move it in global scope, because the variable isn't declared at global scope. Scope isn't the same thing as storage. Scope denotes where the variable can be accessed from - moving it to the global scope would mean that it can be accessed from anywhere, which isn't the case here.

The second part of the program exhibits **undefined behavior**. `addrs` contains dangling pointers after the function exits. Because `std::set` compares the existing pointers on insertion, this is illegal. So I'd say yes, `res2` can vary, but because of the UB, not the reason you suspect.

Comment: I think it doesn't exhibit UB unless one of those pointers are dereferenced.

Comment: @VladLazarenko it does. You can't compare pointers outside of an array (or one past the end). Moreover, operations other than assignment on invalid pointers are illegal (including copying) - it's counter-intuitive, I know, but true.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: You can compare unrelated pointers using `std::less` rather than `<`, and therefore you can store them in a set. But your second reason (the pointers being invalid) is enough to make the behaviour undefined.